# Unable to get response using oci-cli

Tags: python, oracle-call-interface

OCI commands such as `oci os ns get` doesn't work

I've tried several other commands like `oci iam compartment list -c $T` but none of them works

```
oci iam compartment list -c $T
```

I expect the output to be of the following response

```
{
"data": "docs"
"id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaal3gzijdhqol2pglie6astxxeyqdqeyg35nz5zxil2rggnx7jnhwa"
"is-stateless": null                            
}
```

But the actual output is `Nothing` and it just hangs

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your configuration files from OCI? They should be in ~/.oci by default. You can re-generate the configuration files using:

```
oci setup config
```

If re-configuring OCI CLI does not work, try checking your firewall settings in your machine. It seems like you have no connectivity to Oracle Cloud, perhaps this helps you.

Comment: Inorder to run installation script on Windows, one must enable "**RemoteSigned execution policy**" and any changes to Windows Registry files requires a system restart. I'm not sure if this fixed the problem for me but its working for me now. Thanks for your help !